# List available serial ports

Tags: ruby, serial-port, detection

I'm looking for a way to list the available serial ports (regardless of the ruby serial port gem). For now, I gave a try to ruby gems below:

- ruby-serialport: https://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport
- rubyserial: https://github.com/hybridgroup/rubyserial

I know how to do that in Python, in .NET /mono C#, Java but I cannot manage to get this information in ruby, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows only

```
require 'rubyserial'

def seach_ports
  ports = []
  1.upto 64 do |index|
    begin
      serial = Serial.new  portname = 'COM' + index.to_s
      ports << portname if serial
      serial.close
    rescue  Exception => e
      ports << portname if e.to_s.include? "ACCESS_DENIED"
    end
  end
  return ports 
end

p ports = seach_ports
```

or with port status

```
require 'rubyserial'

def seach_ports
  ports = {}
  1.upto 64 do |index|
    begin
      serial = Serial.new  portname = 'COM' + index.to_s
      ports[portname] = 'is available' if serial
      serial.close
    rescue  Exception => e
      ports[portname] = 'access denied' if e.to_s.include? "ACCESS_DENIED"
    end
  end
  return ports 
end

p seach_ports
```